# How to use the Alertcondition feature right, I am doing something wrong?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to use the Alertfunction in pinescript. I'm a noob at coding and want to modify something existing.

//Alerts

```
plotshape(longCondition, title = "Buy Signal", text ="LONG", textcolor = white, style=shape.labelup, size = size.normal, location=location.belowbar, color = green, transp = 0)
plotshape(shortCondition, title = "Sell Signal", text ="SHORT", textcolor = white, style=shape.labeldown, size = size.normal, location=location.abovebar, color = red, transp = 0)

alertcondition(longCondition,title="Long",message="Long @ ..")
alertcondition(shortCondition,title="Short",message="Short @ .. ")
```

I want the long alert to be selectable when the strategy is having a buy alert and versa vise for a short.

If anyone can help me there what I'm missing or doing wrong, I would appreciate it.

Strategy is compileable but nothing selectable when I want to create an alert with tradingview.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't create alerts that way using a strategy. See [here](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/strategy-alerts-are-live-now-18770/) to learn how alerts work for strategies.